# iOS 5.0 simulator: GKLeaderBoardViewController not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, game-center

The following piece of code works nice on iOS 6.0 (both simulator and device). The game center is presented allright. But it does nothing on iOS 5.0 simulator. Unfortunately I don't have a device with iOS 5.0, so I can't check if it is a simulator-related issue.

```
- (void)showLeaderboard:(NSString *)leaderboard
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController * leaderboardViewController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    leaderboardViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [leaderboardViewController setCategory:leaderboard];
    [leaderboardViewController setLeaderboardDelegate:self];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
    [leaderboardViewController release];
}
```

So what happens? Nothing. No view is presented. It doesn't log any messages into the console. It does not even reach the completion block.
I tried to play around and here is what I've managed to figure out. I use  CustomLeaderboardViewController inherited from `GKLeaderboardViewController` instead of pure `GKLeaderboardViewController`, and place a breakpoint in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method. It does not fire with the code above. But if I use 
`setCategory:nil` 
instead of 
`setCategory:leaderboard`
then that breakpoint fires. Still nothing happens further and the completion block is not called.
Any thoughts why could such a thing happen?

Comment: A couple things to check: Are you sure that neither leaderboardViewController and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController are non-nil? What about leaderboard? Have you also tried switching between debug and release to ensure that your leaderboard is not being released prematurely? Do you see any log output in the console?

Comment: Yes, you were right, the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController was nil. What a silly mistake! That's where you get when you copy-paste too much :(.

Comment: Cool! I'd really appreciate if you mark my latest answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that none of your variables (e.g., 'leaderboard') are non-nil, as Objective C likes to fail silently in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be just a silly mistake. [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController was nil, because it was never set in case of iOS 5.0.